# Examples of T-conductor?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

I am struggling with understanding the concept of a T-conductor in linear algebra. I do know the definition, but some examples would be helpful.

**Definition.** Let $W$ be an invariant subspace for $T$ and let $\alpha$ be a vector in $V$. The $T$-conductor of $\alpha$ into $W$ is the set $S_T(\alpha;W)$, which consists of all polynomials $g$ (over the scalar field) such that $g(T)\alpha$ is in $W$. (p.201, Sec. 6.4)

I need some examples of T-conductor

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Note that the term "T-conductor" is not universally used; it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the definition as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2452669/81360)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. Let $T:\Bbb C^4 \to \Bbb C^4$ be the transformation associated with the Jordan-form matrix
$$
\pmatrix{\mu&1&0&0\\0&\mu&0&0\\ 0&0&\lambda&1\\0&0&0&\lambda}.
$$
Let $W$ denote the subspace spanned by the vector $e_1 = (1,0,0,0)$. Let $e_1,\dots,e_4$ denote the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$. We now describe $S_T(\alpha;W)$ for several different vectors $\alpha$:

1. For any $\alpha \in W$, $S_T(\alpha;W)$ is the set of **all** polynomials
2. For $\alpha = e_2$, $S_T(\alpha;W)$ is the set of polynomials divisible by $p(t) = (t-\mu)$
3. For $\alpha = e_3$, $S_T(\alpha;W)$ is the set of polynomials divisible by $p(t) = (t-\lambda)$
4. For any $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$ with $\alpha_2 \neq 0$ and $\alpha_4 \neq 0$, $S_T(\alpha;W)$ is the set of polynomials divisible by $(t-\mu)(t-\lambda)^2$.
5. For any $v \in \Bbb C^4$ and $\alpha = e_1 + v$, $S_T(\alpha;W) = S_T(v;W)$

Comment: Can you please be a little more elaborate... I'm also having some problems with $T$-conductors and I can't understand how you are getting the formulas for $S_T(\alpha;W)$ in each of the cases. It would be nice if you can add a line or two explaining how you're getting the results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SayanDutta I'm not sure how to explain the thought process "in a line or two". I would recommend that you post a new question that links to this one and explains your issue.

Comment: @Sayan Are you able to show that these are correct for cases 1,2, and 3?

Comment: I did post a new question asking about $T$T-conductors. Here's the link- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4227314/943723. See if you can help.

Comment: I can understand case 1 very well, but not the others :(

Comment: I'll take a look at your question. In the mean time, I recommend that you spend some time thinking about 2 and 3. In particular, try to answer (and prove the answer to) this question: what is the **lowest-degree** polynomial for which $g(T) \alpha \in W$? If you put this together with the fact that the $T$-conductor has a polynomial ideal, then you get the answer.

Comment: Okay, sure! Please have a look at the question.